# Unable to create Redshift tables using aws nodejs sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-redshift

I am looking at Redshift

[sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Redshift.html)

and can't seem to find a method wherein i can programmatically create tables and define rows for a database.

Can't figure out what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't create tables in Redshift via the AWS SDK. You would perform that type of database function by connecting to Redshift using a PostgreSQL database driver. The AWS SDK is for creating and managing the server resources, you still connect to the database in a more traditional way to execute SQL commands.